# Checkout a repo B from repo A, update and git push changes

Tags: github-actions, continuous-deployment, cicd

I have a repository https://github.com/Gitauwairimu/ghjavamvn.git whose github actions workflow builds and pushes a docker image. It also checkouts another repo https://github.com/Gitauwairimu/GitOps--ghjavamvn.git and successfully updates a file base/base/deployment.yaml with the new image. How can this changes be pushed back to the repo https://github.com/Gitauwairimu/GitOps--ghjavamvn.git using git?

Am using:

```
    git config user.name "me"
    git config user.email "xxxx@gmail.com"
    git add base/deployment.yaml
    git commit -m 'updated k8s manifest image version'
    git push https://${{ secrets.k8s_REPO_UPDATE }}@github.com/Gitauwairimu/GitOps--ghjavamvn.git
    git push origin main
```

Its not working. The issue seems to be the second last command.

Comment: Could you share the rest of your workflow to see how you checkout both repositories?

Comment: - name: Checkout K8s manifest repo
         uses: actions/checkout@v2
         with:
           repository: Gitauwairimu/GitOps--ghjavamvn
           ref: 'main'
           token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
           path: ./base
           env:
             GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.k8s_REPO_UPDATE }}``

Comment: Its a public repo. Find the workflow file here: https://github.com/Gitauwairimu/ghjavamvn/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml @GuiFalourd

Comment: locally cloning the repo, updating files and using the same processing in pushing changes works

Comment: What happens when executing directly `git push origin main` ?

Comment: I am then prompted to key i my Github login details but from my local machine am successful in pushing the git changes when I use: git push https://<token>@github.com//Gitauwairimu/GitOps--ghjavamvn.git -f

Comment: What is the `ACTIONS_RUNNER_TOKEN` secret scope permission? Moreover, you shared `github.com//Gitauwairimu` in the URL, but it should be `github.com/Gitauwairimu` (with `/` and not `//`).

Comment: I have rectified that. Now I get: fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address

Comment: I have given all repo and workflow permisions to the token. I now get the error: error: src refspec https://Gitauwairimu does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Gitauwairimu/GitOps--ghjavamvn'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.